# Check all data in every 10 second in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

There is **cases collection** which stores cases.Each case is being assigned to 5 users from user collection to **evaluate** the case let's call them assigned Users.These assigned users are stored in an array inside each case Object in **cases collection** . If any of the assigned user don't answer within **2 minutes**  I have to reassign to another user.So I decided to write an interval function and call it in every 10 seconds.As this function will check all documents in cases collection in every 10 will anything go wrong ?? If yes is there any alternative method ?

```
let the_interval = 10000; //10sec
setInterval(async function() {
    try {
        await gradingModule.removeUnansweredUsers();
        console.log("10 sec check");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("10 sec check error:", e);
    }
}, the_interval);
```

Comment: as long as you don't have more entries than would fit in an excel spreadsheet you should be fine ;) if not, handle the timeout and check in the application logic. there you should know exactly what users to check on.